# Trading View Chart Widget inside a React component is getting rendered twice

Tags: reactjs

`TradingViewWidget` is the component inside which I am trying to embed Trading View's widget. The problem is I am unable to figure out why I'm getting 2 duplicates of the same widget.

I found out that the `TradingViewWidget` component is not facing rerendering issue but still duplicating the widget.

TradingViewWidget.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, memo } from "react";

function TradingViewWidget() {
  const container = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-overview.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.innerHTML = `
        {
          "symbols": [
            [
              "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD|7D"
            ]
          ],
          "chartOnly": false,
          "width": "100%",
          "height": "100%",
          "locale": "en",
          "colorTheme": "light",
          "autosize": true,
          "showVolume": false,
          "showMA": false,
          "hideDateRanges": false,
          "hideMarketStatus": true,
          "hideSymbolLogo": false,
          "scalePosition": "left",
          "scaleMode": "Normal",
          "fontFamily": "Arial, sans-serif",
          "fontSize": "10",
          "noTimeScale": false,
          "valuesTracking": "1",
          "changeMode": "price-and-percent",
          "chartType": "area",
          "maLineColor": "#2962FF",
          "maLineWidth": 1,
          "maLength": 9,
          "gridLineColor": "rgba(91, 156, 246, 0.14)",
          "lineWidth": 2,
          "lineType": 0,
          "dateRanges": [
            "1d|3",
            "1w|1D",
            "1m|1D",
            "3m|1D",
            "6m|1D",
            "12m|1M",
            "all|12M"
          ],
          "lineColor": "rgba(91, 156, 246, 1)",
          "topColor": "rgba(187, 217, 251, 0.2)",
          "bottomColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.39)",
          "dateFormat": "dd MMM",
          "timeHoursFormat": "24-hours"
        }`;
    container.current.appendChild(script);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="tradingview-widget-container flex justify-center mx-auto mt-5 lg:mt-0 border-4 border-red-500 min-w-96 h-96 md:w-5/6 md:h-3/4 lg:w-4/5 lg:h-[45rem]" ref={container}>
      <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
      <div className="tradingview-widget-copyright">
        <a
          href="https://www.tradingview.com/"
          rel="noopener nofollow"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <span className="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(TradingViewWidget);
```

Below is the ScreenShot of My Browser:
[image]

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import AppLayout from './components/AppLayout'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import TradingViewWidget from './components/Body/LeftBody/CoinGraph/TradingViewWidget'
import Error from './components/Error/Error'
import Body from './components/Body/Body'

const App = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <AppLayout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <Body />,
        },
        {
          path: "/coin",
          element: <TradingViewWidget />,
        }
      ],
      errorElement: <Error />
    }
  ])

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  )
}

export default App
```

I want to stop the `TradingViewWidget` from being duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

1. The duplication of the widget is happening because of the new behavior of React 18 strict mode - https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#new-strict-mode-behaviors

To avoid this, you need to perform a cleanup effect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const currentContainer = container.current;
  
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  // init the script element 

  currentContainer.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    currentContainer.removeChild(script);
  };
}, []);
```

2. The way you are modifying the DOM doesn't appear to be React-safe.

https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs

> **Avoid changing DOM nodes managed by React.** Modifying, adding children to, or removing children from elements that are managed by React can lead to inconsistent visual results or crashes like above.

> However, this doesn’t mean that you can’t do it at all. It requires caution. **You can safely modify parts of the DOM that React has no reason to update.** For example, if some `<div>` is always empty in the JSX, React won’t have a reason to touch its children list. Therefore, it is safe to manually add or remove elements there.

Appending the widget to an empty `<div>` would be safer.